# jqrid readonly cell needs to be automatically updated after an inline edit

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqrid and I use inline editing. The problem is one of the cells is read only and it's value is based on another:

```
{ name: 'ActivityId', index: 'ActivityId', width: 200, align:'left', editable: true, editrules: { required : true }, edittype:"select", editoptions: { dataUrl: '/Invoice/GetActivities/' + organisationId,
                            buildSelect: function(data) {
                                var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                                var s = '<select>';

                                if(response.rows && response.rows.length) {
                                for (var i = 0, l=response.rows.length; i<l ; i++) {
                                         var ri = response.rows[i];
                                         s += '<option value="'+ri.Id+'">'+ri.Descriptor+'</option>';
                                     }
                                 }
                                 return s + "</select>";

                                return s;
                            }
                } },

              { name: 'PriceGroup', index: 'PriceGroup', align: 'center', editable: false },
```

So the value in the `PriceGroup` column is calculated based on what the `ActivityId` is.

So it's fine when loading the grid but after performing an edit this cell is having the value related to the previous `ActivityId`.

The right value is restored after I manually click refresh.

I'm wondering how to get this value to come through correctly after an edit. Should I somehow refresh the grid after edits in the code? How would yo do this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing), you can pass the editRow function a success function:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('editRow',rowid, keys, oneditfunc, succesfunc, url, extraparam, aftersavefunc,errorfunc, afterrestorefunc);
```

From here, you can get and set row items by passing a function like:

```
function(rowid){
   var dataColumn = 2;
   var dataValue = $('#grid_id').getCell(rowId,dataColumn);
   var resultColumn = 3;
   $('#grid_id').setCell(rowId,resultColumn,dataValue*5+1);
}
```